# Displaying HTML table from PHP array with two headers

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array containing sport results that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alexander
            [distance] => 60
            [value] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alexander
            [distance] => 100
            [value] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alexander
            [distance] => 200
            [value] => 11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alexander
            [distance] => 400
            [value] => 12
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dmitriy
            [distance] => 60
            [value] => 5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dmitriy
            [distance] => 100
            [value] => 6
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dmitriy
            [distance] => 200
            [value] => 7
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dmitriy
            [distance] => 400
            [value] => 8
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sergei
            [distance] => 60
            [value] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sergei
            [distance] => 100
            [value] => 2
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sergei
            [distance] => 200
            [value] => 3
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sergei
            [distance] => 400
            [value] => 4
        )
)
```

I need to display the array data in a specific way in a html table, that should look like this. Top header should contain all unique values from "distance" key and left header should contain all unique values from "name" key:

```
           |  60  |  100  |  200  |  400
===========================================
Alexnader  |  9   |  10   |   11  |  12
===========================================
Dmitriy    |  5   |   6   |   7   |   8
===========================================
Sergei     |  1   |   2   |   3   |   4
```

How can I do it the fastest way, with the least number of loops or using php array methods? Thank you.

Comment: this is php array? post array here instead of output of print_r()

Comment: @DevsiOdedra This is a print_r() output of an array.

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself so far?

Comment: Maybe there are some better ways of organizing data in the array, so you can print them easily as you want !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get unique distances and names for the table.

```php
$names = array_unique(array_map(fn($a) => $a['name'], $data));
$dists = array_unique(array_map(fn($a) => $a['distance'], $data));
```

Make a function to find by name and distance for table values.

```php
function findValue($dist, $name, $data): string {
    foreach($data as $d) {
        if($d['name'] != $name || $d['distance'] != $dist ) continue;
        return (string) $d['value'];
    }
    return '';
}
```

Now out output the table beginning with the head and distances

```php
echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr><th></th>", implode('', array_map(fn($col) => "<th>$col</th>", $dists)), "</tr>\n";
```

Put out the data by row for each name using our find function

```php
foreach($names as $name) {
    $row = [];
    foreach($dists as $dist) {
        $row[] = '<td>' . findValue($dist, $name, $data) . '</td>';
    }
    $rowText = join('', $row);
    echo "<tr><td>$name</td>$rowText</tr>\n";
}
```

Finally close the table.

```php
echo "</table>\n";
```

The result is

```html
<table>
<tr><th></th><th>60</th><th>100</th><th>200</th><th>400</th></tr>
<tr><td>Alexander</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>Dmitriy</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sergei</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

We have to restructure the array first

```
$array = Array
(
    "0" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Alexander",
        "distance" => 60,
        "value" => 9
    ),

    "1" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Alexander",
        "distance" => 100,
        "value" => 10
    ),

    "2" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Alexander",
        "distance" => 200,
        "value" => 11
    ),

    "3" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Alexander",
        "distance" => 400,
        "value" => 12
    ),

    "4" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Dmitriy",
        "distance" => 60,
        "value" => 5
    ),

    "5" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Dmitriy",
        "distance" => 100,
        "value" => 6
    ),

    "6" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Dmitriy",
        "distance" => 200,
        "value" => 7
    ),

    "7" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Dmitriy",
        "distance" => 400,
        "value" => 8
    ),

    "8" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Sergei",
        "distance" => 60,
        "value" => 1
    ),

    "9" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Sergei",
        "distance" => 100,
        "value" => 2
    ),

    "10" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Sergei",
        "distance" => 200,
        "value" => 3
    ),

    "11" => Array
    (
        "name" => "Sergei",
        "distance" => 400,
        "value" => 4
    )
);

$table_heading = array_unique(array_column($array, "distance"));

$restructured_array = [];
foreach($array as $row){
    if(!isset($restructured_array[$row["name"]])){
        $restructured_array[$row["name"]] = [];
    }
    $restructured_array[$row["name"]][$row["distance"]] = $row["value"];
}
```

Now the array can be looped to print the table.

```
echo "<table><thead><tr>";
echo "<th></th>";
foreach($table_heading as $heading){ 
    echo "<th>".$heading."</th>";
}
echo "</tr></thead>";
echo "<tbody>"; 
foreach ($restructured_array as $key=>$rows){
    echo "<tr><th>".$key."</th>";
    foreach ($rows as $k=>$row){
         echo "<td>".$row."</td>";
    }
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

The output will be

```
           60   100 200 400
Alexander   9   10  11  12
Dmitriy     5   6   7   8
Sergei      1   2   3   4
```